# Amadeus flight search API,Flight Offers API and Flight Booking API Using JavaScript Fetch

Tags: javascript, html, amadeus

I will need experienced coders on Amadeus Flight APIs. Now I have to combine all three APIs. Display search results which I can do easily. How do I determine/get the id of the flight chosen by a traveller, feed it to the Flight Offers API and Finally get it to the Flight Booking API? This might be easy for some people, but I am trying to wrap my head around it. I will be happy to get a first hand idea.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/tutorial-booking-engine-amadeus-flight-booking-api) (blog + video) explaining how to build a flight booking engine by combining the 3 APIs:

- Flight Offers Search
- Flight Offers Price
- Flight Create Orders